# Is it a good practice to capture build artifacts in Artifactory that Jenkins produces?

Tags: version-control, continuous-integration, jenkins

We use Jenkins to run continuous integration builds. The output of these builds might be EAR files, WAR files, or just a collection of files that are TAR'd up.

To this point we have used Jenkins to manage the produced artifacts.

We have Artifactory deployed in-house. Would it be a bad idea to leverage Artifactory to capture the produced artifacts?

Or is Artifactory meant to hold JARs with versions that can be pulled into projects with Maven when building and not meant to capture artifacts that a continuous integration tool uses?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891890/should-artifactory-not-be-used-to-capture-the-build-artifacts-that-jenkins-produ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ArtifactoryPro has features for doing what you're asking, so why the heck not?  JFrog's documentation even has an example: see http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Build+Integration